# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\\' on input line 86

Tags: latex, resume

Hey I am getting the following error

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\' on input line 86.

I've tried the following

```
\subsection{University of North Carolina \\ at Chapel Hill}

\subsection{{University of North Carolina} {\\} {at Chapel Hill}}
```

Answer (score 5):

- this is a warning and not an error message
- manually putting formatting instructions in macros like `\subsection` is bad style. If you want your subsections to appear in a certain way, you should redefine their appearance instead.
- using `\\` for line breaks is also bad. You shouldn't use it outside of tabular and similar environments.
- if you really must use it, provide an alternative string which hyperref can use to create the pdf bookmarks

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}


\subsection{\texorpdfstring{University of North Carolina \\ at Chapel Hill}{University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill}}


\end{document}
```